# Dbcontext.Savechanges() in the for-each loop, best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a `foreach` loop and within that loop I insert record into a table and at the same time I send email for each item in that loop.

I read that somewhere that its best practice to have fewer `dbcontext.savechanges()` so decided to keep that out of for each loop.

Now if something breaks in `savechanges()`, emails would be sent as the logic is before savechanges.

What should be the best option here?

Comment: Send the emails after calling `savechanges()`?

Comment: For this, I would need to save those item details somewhere as email is sent for each item I add in the database. Might be heavy.

Comment: You already have the objects you are using to write the changes. Can't you use those?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice I can recommend is not to mix this sort of functionality in one class. This relates to the Single Responsibility Principle, which recommends having a class do one thing. It's also described as a class having one reason to change.

Here are some of the things that happen when we mix that up:

- We need to switch to a different database or ORM. That could be significant work, but now we need to also work on our email-sending code. Will we move it into the new database code? Where will it go? Now that change is more complicated.
- When we fix a bug in our email code or our database code, we're also touching the code that does the other thing, because they're in the same class, perhaps even the same methods. There's a risk that we'll introduce a defect into something we didn't even need to change.
- Testing both becomes more difficult. Imagine if every time you touch your database code you have to make sure that records are written to the database *and* emails are sent. And the same if we change the database code.

Issues like this aren't possible - they're close to inevitable, unless we write the code once and never need to change it again. And they don't happen when it's convenient.

Separating things like this makes our lives easier (and the next person's) because it reduces the number of unrelated things we have to think about and work on at one time.

---

One approach would be to save all of the changes to your database as part of a transaction. The transaction isn't committed, or final, until all of the changes are saved. If your data gets partially saved, the emails are only part of the problem.

If your application executes the code to save changes and it returns without throwing an exception, that means *all* of your changes are saved. Then you can send emails (using separate code written just for that purpose.) You can roll back database changes if some fail, but if you've started sending emails you can't roll those back.

For further reading I'd look for articles and answers that combine "unit of work" and "transactions." It's a pattern commonly used with Entity Framework. [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) directly relates to a web application.